# disconnected from meteor server

Tags: meteor

Several times per hour, all users (about 100) are disconnected from meteor server. And they cannot reconnect. The status flag remains false. I am then obliged to deploy again the application on meteor server to get it available. I dont see any thing abnormal in logs. Any idea about the cause of this problem ?

Comment: are you at something.meteor.com or your own hosting?